# jquery validation required field works only if field was once active.

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Sorry for general question. I have form    id = "formID", validator for this form and some elements with classses "required". How should I write onclick method for Save button, so that it wouldn't work if some of the inputs are empty?

```
function onSaveButtonClicked() {
if(!($("#formID").valid())) {return};
```

I tried this, but it's not working if user click on button before editing some fields.
i.e. if user edit field than erase everything in it - it will work, euther way - not.

Comment: I believe you are using some external jQuery plugin for validating. Please provide the name / url of it. Also is #formID added to DOM via javascript or is it part of initial html

Comment: You need to include more code!  The idea here is to provide enough code for a concise example of your problem.  Where is `.validate()`?  Where is your `<form>`?  Where is the button you're talking about?

Comment: Also, your title has almost nothing to do with what you've asked in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a closing brace `}`. Also, `return false` will prevent the form submission if it is invalid **NOT** `return`. Try this:

```
function onSaveButtonClicked() {
    if(!($("#formID").valid())) {
        return false;
    }
}
```